# Can I pay for membership from another card?

Tags: ios, developer-program

I'm apple developer. A few years ago I registered an account from one card. Can I pay for membership from another card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

The Apple Developer account isn’t locked to your credit card. You can make use of any valid/active credit card to make payment towards your membership renewal.